# Best methods for running dart server?

Tags: ubuntu, dart, init

I have a http server I have written in Dart that I plan on deploying to Linux vm's. Right now, my test / demo server is on a Ubuntu digital ocean droplet. Does anyone have a good init script or a better method than using a linux init service script?

EDIT:

My Init script as of now:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          dart
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Starts Dart
# Description:       This will start the dart runtime and in turn, start
### END INIT INFO

# Author: David Marchbanks <ptdave20@gmail.com>

# Do NOT "set -e"

# PATH should only include /usr/* if it runs after the mountnfs.sh script
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Dart Server"
NAME=dart
DAEMON=/usr/bin/$NAME
DART_SERVER=/home/dart/server/bin/server.dart
DAEMON_ARGS="$DART_SERVER"
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.2-14) to ensure that this file is present
# and status_of_proc is working.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been started
    #   1 if daemon was already running
    #   2 if daemon could not be started
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS || return 2
    # Add code here, if necessary, that waits for the process to be ready
    # to handle requests from services started subsequently which depend
    # on this one.  As a last resort, sleep for some time.
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been stopped
    #   1 if daemon was already stopped
    #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
    #   other if a failure occurred
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
    RETVAL="$?"
    [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks
    # and if the daemon is only ever run from this initscript.
    # If the above conditions are not satisfied then add some other code
    # that waits for the process to drop all resources that could be
    # needed by services started subsequently.  A last resort is to
    # sleep for some time.
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry=0/30/KILL/5 --exec $DAEMON
    [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    return "$RETVAL"
}

#
# Function that sends a SIGHUP to the daemon/service
#
do_reload() {
    #
    # If the daemon can reload its configuration without
    # restarting (for example, when it is sent a SIGHUP),
    # then implement that here.
    #
    start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 1 --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
    return 0
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_start
    case "$?" in
        0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  stop)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
        0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  status)
    status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
    ;;
  #reload|force-reload)
    #
    # If do_reload() is not implemented then leave this commented out
    # and leave 'force-reload' as an alias for 'restart'.
    #
    #log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC" "$NAME"
    #do_reload
    #log_end_msg $?
    #;;
  restart|force-reload)
    #
    # If the "reload" option is implemented then remove the
    # 'force-reload' alias
    #
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
      0|1)
        do_start
        case "$?" in
            0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
            1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
            *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
        esac
        ;;
      *)
        # Failed to stop
        log_end_msg 1
        ;;
    esac
    ;;
  *)
    #echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload}" >&2
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart|force-reload}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac

:
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896836

Comment: Yes, I have an init script now that when I watch the VM boot, it gets to the service and hangs. Can still remote in and do everything else, but just hangs. Ideally, I'd like to keep the service as simple / universal as possible without extra installs.

Comment: I haven't seen anything else yet besides the linked question (this doesn't mean because I haven't got much experience in running servers). Maybe you can provide more information about your problem with your current attempt. It might evolve that this question is a better fit for superuser.com or serverfault.com though.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend using Docker (https://www.docker.com/) container for incapsulating your Dart app.

Here is a good example on how to "dockerize" Dart application: http://www.nkode.io/2014/03/05/dockerize-dart.html

So in general:

1. You add a `Dockerfile` like this: https://github.com/nkratzke/containerdart/blob/master/Dockerfile to your application
2. Run/Test your application locally via `docker run ...`
3. When you're ready, deploy app to your server, and add autostart of your docker container as it described here: https://docs.docker.com/articles/host_integration/

This method will allow you to develop on any OS (Docker uses VMs  for non-linux OSes), and be sure that your app will work on your production server.

Actually it is much simpler than it sounds, but unify process, so you can easily host your app on any "docker-friendly" hosting, not only DigitalOcean, but also Amazon EC2, Google Compute, or even Microsoft's Azure.